# ABAP SWC macros. Are they part of the language?

Tags: abap

In a customer object, we found an SWC statement that our parser chokes on.

```
  IF NOT ( pyparaid IS INITIAL OR dataset_exp IS INITIAL ).
    swc_set_element container 'DATASET' dataset_exp+10.
  ENDIF.
```

Although [this page](http://scn.sap.com/community/bpm/business-workflow/blog/2013/05/29/useful-sap-business-object-type-programming-macros) seems to imply that they are well known in the ABAP world, I cannot find a page where they are documented officially.  (Similar to the ABAP keyword documentation).

Are these macros considered part of the language? In other words, if they are not covered, would you consider a parser incomplete?  Please point me to their documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try searching for yourself next time. The first hit when googling for "site:help.sap.com swc_set_element" would have lead you straight to [the reference](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/c5/e4b130453d11d189430000e829fbbd/content.htm).

Yes, a parser that is unable to process macros is incomplete. [You have been warned about that half a year ago...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28361835/218890) :-)

Comment: Thanks. Well, I did google it. It appears, my search strings were inferior